# Does Keycloak API has any endpoint to update account email?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to change account email in Keycloak, but did not find any useful information in the Keycloak official documentation.

I tried work with this endpoint

```
PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email
```

but it only accepts an array of actions and sends to a user an email to perform specified actions.

But I want to update it directly performing my request. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for below API.

```
PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}
```

with a JSON payload as below.

```
{
    "email":"new@email.com" 
}
```